# Obter retorno de fetch com await/async

Tags: javascript, promises, fetch

```
recebe();   

async function recebe(){

   const {url} = await pegaValores();

   console.log(url);
}

async function pegaValores(){

    return fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dba68fb3000007400028eb5')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data =>{return data})
}
```

No `console.log(url)` está retornado `undefined`, gostaria que retornasse o objeto.

Comment: Sempre tome cuidado com as concatenações de async e API assíncronas como a Fetch API.
Como pegaValores é async e retorna um fetch o await pegaValores() vai esperar apenas o fetch ser retornado e não o resultado do fetch, por isso url está como undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alguns testes e tive os seguintes resultados:

- Acessando essa API mocky.io sem a utilização de HTTPS gera algumas
  exceções durante a utilização do fetch, portanto será necessário
  substituir o http por https:

```
fetch('https://www.mocky.io/v2/5dba68fb3000007400028eb5');
```

- Você cria a constante da seguinte forma: const {url}, não compreendi
  o porque, mas assim não funciona, você poderia simplesmente remover
  as chaves nesse trecho:

```
const url = await pegaValores();
```

- Por fim na função pegaValores, como trata-se de uma função
  assíncrona, você pode utilizar do fetch com await:

```
await fetch('https://www.mocky.io/v2/5dba68fb3000007400028eb5')
```

---

No final o código ficou da seguinte forma:

```
recebe();   

async function recebe(){
  const url = await pegaValores();

  console.log(url);
}

async function pegaValores(){
  return await fetch('https://www.mocky.io/v2/5dba68fb3000007400028eb5').then( result => result.json());
}
```

---

Caso queira testar, aqui está um exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/VisibleDarkredTechnician

Comment: Se eu quiser pegar um valor especifico tipo login ainda não consigo

Comment: Consegue sim, essa API retorna um array com diversos objetos, dá uma olhada nesse exemplo onde é impresso o login no console: https://repl.it/repls/BriskStickyGnuassembler

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score -3):

O problema aqui é que a função `pegaValores()` está retornando uma promessa (`Promise`) em vez de retornar diretamente os dados obtidos pela requisição. Quando a função `recebe()` é executada, ela tenta acessar o valor da propriedade `url` antes que a promessa retorne os dados, resultando em um valor `undefined`.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode utilizar a palavra chave `await` antes da chamada da função `pegaValores()` dentro de `recebe()`, o que fará com que a função aguarde a resolução da promessa antes de prosseguir. Ficaria assim:

```js
async function recebe(){
   const {url} = await pegaValores();
   console.log(url);
}

async function pegaValores(){
    const response = await fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dba68fb3000007400028eb5');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```